# Sample code on how to render a URL response (text) in RSS format

Tags: java, url, rss, rendering, response

I need help with generating a way to render response from a URL in RSS format. Could someone please help me with a sample code of how to go about it? I am coding in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by render response? render to what?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Rome library at http://rometools.org/. You should find the source code samples on how to generate a RSS/ ATOM feed in Java. You will have to call the Rome library in your servlet to output the RSS data